# java lang verify error

Tags: java

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: a method: parse signature: 
()Z) Incompatible argument to function

public boolean parse() {


}
```

What does this error mean and how to fix these kind of errors

Comment: Can you give a *complete* code example together with some background info about which JVM you're using, host platform, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this kind of error is related to version problems, you are compiling with a different version of a library than you are running with. There are also some quite subtle varieties of this that can occur with java 1.5 type coercion, where a 1.4 compiler would choose differently. Recompile everything with 1.5, and make sure you're using the same versions.

Answer (score 2):

It usually is about a java 1.5 or 6 compatibility issue (like trying to compile a Java5 or 6 code with an older 1.4 javac).

Clean all your .class files and rebuild from scratch, checking that you have your JDK and JRE at the same level.

---

It can also be a bad typecast from a third party class method "return items" to your local ones.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this:

> Thrown when the "verifier" detects
>   that a class file, though well formed,
>   contains some sort of internal
>   inconsistency or security problem.
>   [Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html)

Have you returned a boolean?

Could you please provide more information, which environment is set? The security question is important, I think.

Answer (score 0):

well, first seems to be that the returning value is missong.
You should return a boolean value.
But this is not the problem.
This kind of exception appears when you make a reference which cannot be resolved,
like an assignement in a loop

for (i=i; i!=XX;i++)

check such references.

Luis